# CSS set default scroll position

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to set the scroll position to a default value?

I know how to do it in javascript, for example with jquery:

```
$("div#divWithScroll").attr("scrollTop",200);
```

But I wanted to do it with css only, I have no idea if it is possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Within boundaries, it is possible:

When you go to the url `www.domain.com/#divWithScroll` then you will scroll down by default.

```
<a href="#divWithScroll">Scroll down</a><!-- clicking this works either -->
<!-- long blablabla -->
<div id="divWithScroll">Scrolled here</div>
```

More on http://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/

Answer (score 18):

No, there's no way to do that in CSS.  Sorry!

Answer (score 10):

It's not really a "style" issue, so it's not something that CSS would cover.