# Center a one page horizontally scrolling site in browser (not centering a div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

When the browser opens up my page, the browser should already be in the center of the whole page.

Meaning: I have a horizontal one-page, which instead of starting from the left and going to the right (e.g. [this](http://deanoakley.com/)), will start in the middle, and be able to scroll to the content on both the right AND the left.

Here is a visual:

[image]

If possible, I'd like to avoid dom-ready scrolling via JavaScript or jQuery (I'm using it for navigational aid and stuff anyways), and use only pure html5/css or at least focusing the screen pre-dom-ready through JavaScript/jQuery.

Two ideas on my part:

a) moving the container to the left e.g. using `margin-left:-x`, but that usually cuts it off.

b) moving the screen to the right from the start.

Alas, I have been too unsavvy to achieve this on my own.

p.s. here my jsfiddle for consistency: http://jsfiddle.net/alexdot/2Dse3/

Comment: Just to be clear... you want a horizontally scrolling container, but you don't want to use JavaScript to control the scrolling, just a horiz scrollbar?

Comment: Don't think there is a pure html5/css solution. - $("#myDiv").Focus();

Comment: oh no. i am using javascript/jquery later to influence the scrolling. what i do NOT want is that the site loads, is on the left, and after loading scrolls to the actual starting area in the middle of the page. i want to avoid letting the user see content that is reserved for in-depth viewing of the site later on.

Comment: Right. You want that, when the page loads, the first thing the viewers see is the middle area. As I said, No can do in "pure HTMl5/CSS"

Comment: I have invented a way to accomplish your goals: A solution composed of the CSS `visibility` attribute and JavaScript (see answer below). Also pay attention to the last note: Account for the users who have disabled JavaScript.

Comment: @Rob W ...... WHO has disabled javascript today. Please..... Rather create a popup saying "are you here to browse nice pages or what?"

Comment: @roXon A true web developer does not ignore any user. Ever heard about browser extensions like [NoScript](http://noscript.net/)?

Comment: Define a "true web developer"!

Comment: Please keep comments constructive and on topic. Extended conversations can be moved to chat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution**
If you want to hide data, add `visibility:hidden;` to the elements with a content which should be kept hidden at the start. Execute my page scrolling code, and finally change `visibility:hidden;` to `visibility:visible`.

What's going to happen?

1. CSS hides the contents of these elements: `visibility:hidden`
2. The Page loads
3. JavaScript causes the page to scroll to the center: `window.scrollTo(..., ...)`
4. JavaScript shows the secret content (outside the view of the browser): `visibility=visible`
5. The user scrolls to the left/right, and is able to read the secret

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Dse3/5/

---

**Scrolling code**
Scrolling the page to the center cannot be achieved with pure CSS/HTML. This can only be done by using JavaScript. For this simple purpose, I'd rather use native JavaScript than including a JQuery plugin (unnecessary server load).

JavaScript code:

```
 window.scrollTo(
     (document.body.offsetWidth -document.documentElement.offsetWidth )/2,
     (document.body.offsetHeight-document.documentElement.offsetHeight)/2
 );
/*
 * window.scrollTo(x,y) is an efficient cross-broser function,
 * which scrolls the document to position X, Y
 * document.body.offsetWidth contains the value of the body's width
 * document.documentElement contains the value of the document's width
 *
 * Logic: If you want to center the page, you have to substract
 * the body's width from the document's width, then divide it
 * by 2.
 */
```

You have to adjust the CSS (see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Dse3/6/)):

```
body {width: 500%}
#viewContainer {width: 100%}
```

A final note. What do you expect when the user has disabled JavaScript? Are they allowed to see the contents of the page? If yes, add this:

```
<noscript>
  <style>
     .page{
       visibility: visible;
     }
  </style>
</noscript>
```

Otherwise, add `<noscript>JavaScript is required to read this page</noscript>`.

Comment: Great Job. But you could do away with the bold and big "SOLUTION"!

Comment: Thanks. The header was indeed too noticeable. I also forgot to add a header at the second part of the answer. Updated answer.

Comment: great job! thanks rob for the solution and extra thanks for the very good and detailed answer!

Answer (score 4):

An easy jQuery solution

```
$(function () {
    scrollTo(($(document).width() - $(window).width()) / 2, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with DOM-ready?

```
$(function() {
    $('body').scrollLeft($('#viewContainer').width() * 2/5);
});
```

[I'm pretty sure it can't be done with CSS alone.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/953083/102441)