# How can I make sure that a web-page opens up with scrollbar in the middle

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am trying to create a *horizontally* scrolling page and I want the page to open with **scroll bar in the middle** so that the user has option to scroll in both left and right directions(by default it opens with scrollbar at left). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated after comment* If the body's width doesn't exceed the browser's viewport: 
**Scrolling inside an element**:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("container"); //div#container
var elemWidth = elem.scrollWidth;
var elemVisibleWidth = elem.offsetWidth;
elem.scrollLeft = (elemWidth - elemVisibleWidth) / 2;
```

---

Use this code to vertically & horizontally center a page (see also: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462611/center-a-one-page-horizontally-scrolling-site-in-browser-not-centering-a-div/7462737#7462737)):

```
 window.scrollTo(
     (document.body.offsetWidth -window.innerWidth )/2,
     (document.body.offsetHeight-window.innerHeight)/2
 );
```

To only center horizontally, use:

```
window.scrollTo((document.body.offsetWidth -window.innerWidth )/2, 0);
```

Comment: `window.inner(Width/Height)` is not supported by IE up to version 8. Your first answer using `documentElement` works better actually.

Comment: @nfechner For a more detailed explanation on how to implement `document.documentElement` in this way, see my other answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462611/center-a-one-page-horizontally-scrolling-site-in-browser-not-centering-a-div/7462737#7462737

Comment: I have my content inside a div#container. So, can I still use scrollTo()?

Comment: @RobW Thanks! I think that'll do it!

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript function [`scrollTo`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp) in the `onload` event. For more information on how to get the current window size, check out [this article](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow).

Answer (score 0):

one possibility is to use javascripts [`scrollto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollTo) when loading the page (simply put this in your [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) or [domready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)-event):

```
window.onload = function(){
  window.scrollTo(100, 100); // (X,Y)
}
```

just set the x/y values to the ones you need.

Answer (score 0):

another way is # href. If you don't have Problem with tail tag added to url

```js
 $("#iwillHelp")[0].click();
```

```css
    body{
    margin: 0;
}

.top{
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
}

.mid{
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
}

.bottom{
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body id="mainBody">
    <div class="top">how to land at the middle of webpage</div>
    <a id="iwillHelp" href="#testCenter"></a>
    <div class="mid" id="testCenter">How to land in this green coloured section</div>
    <div class="bottom">Please help me</div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```