# Scrolling Position Start in the middle

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm building a horizontal scrolling page with a width of 3000px, what I want to do is: once you enter the page you start in the middle, then you can scroll either left or right. is that possible? I'm sure it is but how? Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make sure that a web-page opens up with scrollbar in the middle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846520/how-can-i-make-sure-that-a-web-page-opens-up-with-scrollbar-in-the-middle)

Comment: `window.scrollTo( 1500 - window.innerWidth/2, 0 )`

Answer (score -2):

As @pawel commented is right :

`window.scrollTo( 1500 - window.innerWidth/2, 0 )`

Comment: Scroll position of `1500` is not the center. On a Full HD display (1980px wide, almost 2/3rds the total width) it would get scrolled all the way to the right. On displays <1500 px the middle would end up on the left edge, not the center, of browser window.

Comment: Well he has a fixed width of 3000 so this has nothing to do with screen display, he just wants ro scroll to the middle which is 1500, this answer is based on the question specifically

Comment: no, if you have 3000px wide document and scroll it horizontally to 1500 then the point at 1500 from left is on the left edge. BUT on a HD display there would be only 1500px to show, so the browser would either need to fill remaining 480px on the right with white space or just scroll as far right as posible (which it will).

Comment: Can you post a link on HD display so that i can understand what you really mean

Comment: The display doesn't really matter here, it was just an example to illustrate the point. scroll position aligns with the edge of browser window while the point of the question is to match the scroll position with the center of browser window. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vmhv7p2c/ (800px width, scroll left set to 400, the div at 400px is nowhere near the center of the window unless the window itself is 800px wide)