# How to make a webpage land at the middle section?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need some idea that how can I make my webpage land in the middle. Like if someone start the page he/she should landing in the middle of webpage.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}

.top{
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
}

.mid{
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
}

.bottom{
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">how to land at the middle of webpage</div>
    <div class="mid">How to land in this green coloured section</div>
    <div class="bottom">Please help me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I vertically center a "div" element for all browsers using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-can-i-vertically-center-a-div-element-for-all-browsers-using-css)

Comment: The marked duplicate is about vertically center; not how to scroll to the middle?

Comment: this is duplicate, but from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390205/jquery-scroll-to-class-name

Comment: Who closed this did not understand question because it is not css style question. In case you are still looking for answer check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846520/how-can-i-make-sure-that-a-web-page-opens-up-with-scrollbar-in-the-middle

Comment: Agree with @Evren. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView), to get scrolled to the `.mid` div automatically.

```js
let mid = document.querySelector(".mid");


mid.scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"});
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}

.top{
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
}

.mid{
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
}

.bottom{
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">how to land at the middle of webpage</div>
    <div class="mid">How to land in this green coloured section</div>
    <div class="bottom">Please help me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @krishnakanta Hope this answers your question.