# Position Absolute: Negative Values

Tags: css

I am attempting to create a page that has four `div` containers that are each 100% width and 100% height. I want there to be a main `div` in the middle, and then one to its left, right, and bottom (yes they must be positioned like this for the sake of jQuery animations).

The following is my current code (and here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MitulP91/P2rjV/)):

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container1"></div>
    <div id="container2"></div>
    <div id="container3"></div>
    <div id="container4"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

#container1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}

#container2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    background-color: red;
}

#container3 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

#container4 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

I had no issue with the `div`s that are to the right and underneath, but I can't seem to get the one to the left working.

I was also trying to position the left `div` at `left: 0` and `top: 0` with the main div at `left: 100%` and `top: 0`, but I am unsure of how to get the page to load viewing the main `div` (the blue one). An example of this is at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MitulP91/zGzLM/).

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you want to do. This isn't correct I assume http://jsfiddle.net/P2rjV/10/

Comment: I would suggest you to use z-index for this purpose!! 
You need not specify any position attributes
just try giving the z-index and in jQuery animations you can change $("#ID").css({z-index:"maxvalue"});

Comment: @KristerAndersson I apologize if I was unclear. I actually want that orange `div` to be to the left of the blue `div`. I did this in the second fiddle that is posted, but I want the page to load to the blue `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your challenge isn't about element positioning - it's about the fact that you need the page to already be scrolled to the horizontal center of your layout upon load. This can only be done via javascript.  [Here's a great q/a on this with a working fiddle.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462611/center-a-one-page-horizontally-scrolling-site-in-browser-not-centering-a-div)

Update: Here's your code updated with the techniques and script from the link above. [View it on Codepen.](http://codepen.io/erquhart/pen/rnCap)

Comment: Thank you so much. Should have seen that. Appreciate the code edit.

Answer (score 0):

it wont work that way
the correct and easy way would be to use javascript to focus on the center div when the page is loading
or made a bigger content div that has all the other divs and change it's position according to the div you want to show [you can add page width to its left property to scroll right etc.]