# How to open website at specific point on page in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, mouse, dreamweaver

beginner programmer so apologies if this is really obvious!

How can i get my website to open at a specific point on the page (in HTML)?

I can't find what this is called anywhere! *Not Anchor etc*. The website will be wider and longer than most screens. **I want the screen/viewport to open at the very centre of a 2500x2500 pixel background**.

I am working in DreamWeaver CC on Mac OS X 10

Thanks in advance!!

*p.s no code to post, this is my first port of call in putting this together*

Answer (score 0):

You can get the client's screen with `$(window).width()` & `$(window).height()` , it's `jQuery` code so  you'll have to add a balise script to the `jQuery` lib on your web page. Can you tell me more about what you want to do ? I have trouble understanding. You don't want any anchor but you want ? Apoligies for not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bit of Javascript to fire when the page loads

```
window.onload = function(){
    window.scrollTo(1250, 1250);
}
```

The `window.scrollTo(x-coord,y-coord)` function takes two parameters, x-coord is the pixel along the horizontal axis of the document that you want displayed in the upper left and y-coord is the pixel along the vertical axis of the document that you want displayed in the upper left.

I picked 1250, because that's 2500 divided  by 2, but you may have to tweak that a little if you want that spot in the middle of the screen. You will have to get the screen's viewport and do some math.

(hint: `window.innerWidth` & `window.innerHeight` gives you the dimensions **including** the scroll bar; `document.documentElement.clientWidth` and `document.documentElement.clientHeight` is **without** the scrollbar)

---

The documentation for `window.scrollTo()` is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Some info about the viewport dimensions can be found here: http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/

Answer (score 0):

As bryguy said, you can calculate the center of your screen and use scrollTo(). Alternatively, if you have a particular element that you want to scroll to, give the element an id and use the scrollIntoView() function. You can also center an invisible div positioning the div absolutely and setting the top and left values to 50%:

HTML

```
<div id="scrollToMe" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;"></div>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('scrollToMe').scrollIntoView();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without jQuery. You can use the native JavaScript function `window.scrollTo()` to scroll to the center.

To calculate the center of the screen all you have to do is:

**For vertical center**

- Determine the height of the viewport: The height of the viewport is stored at `document.documentElement.clientHeight`.
- Determine the height of the entire document: You can use `document.documentElement.offsetHeight` or `document.body.scrollHeight` to get the height of the entire document.
- Calculate: Now simply subtract the viewport height from the document height and divide it by two like this:
  `(document.documentElement.offsetHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight)/2`

**For horizontal center**

- Determine the width of the viewport: The width of the viewport is stored at `document.documentElement.clientWidth`.
- Determine the width of the entire document: You can use `document.body.scrollWidth` to accomplish this.
- Calculate: Now simply subtract the viewport width from the document width and divide it by two like this:
  `(document.body.scrollWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth)/2`

**Now time to scroll**

Finally, you'll want to make the window scroll to the calculated point.

```
window.scrollTo(centerWidth, centerHeight);
```

If you want to do all of it in one step, you'd do:

```
window.scrollTo( (document.body.scrollWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth)/2, (document.body.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight)/2 );
```

Please note that we've used document.documentElement.clientHeight (and clientWidth) and they give you the viewport size *without* the scrollbars. If you wish to include the scrollbars you'll have to use other variables. You can find examples of how to get those measurements on the internet.

For more information: [Center a one page horizontally scrolling site in browser (not centering a div)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462611/center-a-one-page-horizontally-scrolling-site-in-browser-not-centering-a-div)